# Double join with the same table using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have following query:

```
select \* from flight
join airport a1
on flight.from_id=a1.id
join airport a2
on flight.to_id=a2.id
where a2.town='pinsk' and a1.town='minsk';
```

How I can create same query using hibernate criteria

I tried using following thing:

code

## **Query that I received**

`Hibernate:

```
select 
    f1_0.id
    ,f1_0.from_id
    ,f1_0.time_arrive
    ,f1_0.time_departure
    , f1_0.to_id 
from flight f1_0 join airport t1_0 on t1_0.id=f1_0.to_id 
    join airport f2_0 on f2_0.id=f1_0.from_id 
    where 1=1 and 1=1 
    offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
```

Comment: and what is the problem with your query?

Comment: @nbk I have condition a2.town='pinsk' and a1.town='minsk' but hibernate generate 1=1 and 1=1 instead

Comment: Then you should post  the code that generates it